# MIPS Relative Addressing

Tags: mips

Can somebody please help me answer these three questions?:

Two identified here: http://s11.postimage.org/lrb0exx5v/Capture2.png When we multiply the immediate operand by 4, do we multiply the binary or the decimal by 2^2? Is the addition sign for concatenation?

What is the maximum offset from $s?: http://s11.postimage.org/emt75wpwj/Capture.png

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processor only deals with binary numbers. Decimals are just a convenient way of displaying binary numbers for humans. The addition sign here represents normal arithmetic addition.

The 16 bit immediate is multiplied by 4 because MIPS instructions are always aligned on a 4 byte boundary, so the lower 2 bits of a legal branch address are always `00`. The offset specifies a **word** offset and is multiplied by 4 to calculate a byte address that is aligned to a 4 byte boundary.

The maximum offset from `$s` is +/- 4 * 2^15, since the immediate value is signed